# What step have i missed? Transferring wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, transfer

So i have recently tried to transfer my wordpress site to another server.

I have followed a few guides, but i definately seem to be missing a step.

Basically what i have done is:

1. export original database (phpMyAdmin)
2. Save all relevant files (ftp)
3. install fresh wordpress on new server. (wp backend)
4. 'drop' all table fields in new wordpress (phpMyAdmin)
5. import original database to new location (phpMyAdmin)
6. transfer theme, plugins, uploads. (ftp)
7. activate theme, plugins. (wp backend)
8. update permalinks. (wp backend)

The problem is, i am left with a default looking wordpress installation, and not my orginal page-home.php and corresponding css.

Also, if i go to wordpress backend SETTINGS > READING > Frontpage:static; i only have the option of 'about', not home, i should have 'home'...

Sorry if i am vague, let me know if any screenshots are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We really need a little more info like:

- when you say plain, do you mean just the theme is not set and you're on the default theme, or there is no theme, or do you mean even your content is not there?
- the site you removed it from, where was the installation located? Was is in the `public_html` folder or a subfolder of that? Did you put it in the same place, ie not inadvertently put it in a different folder
- (I've actually typed the bulk of the post and come back to the top for this one, but):

**Are you sure you're checking the right site?**

- Have you kept the same domain name?
- Has the domain name propagated to the new server?
- Is the CSS being loaded from the correct domain (has anything been hardcoded to the old server)

Let's go through a few broader options:

## 1. Check how many WordPress installs are on your domain

First off, it sounds like you *may* have two WordPress installations. If you have the backend setup correctly with your themes but you're seeing a plain site, it sounds like you're looking at another install. I'm not saying you do have multiple installs, but it is a place to start looking.

A question to ask yourself here is: In this plain looking site, do you see your content, or the content of a default site? If you see your content, you may jump ahead to section 2.

If you're saying there *is* a home page but you're not seeing it as available under static pages, either:

- You're looking at another site (but there should be a home page* even in a default setup—from memory), or
- You're Home Page title may have changed, or have become "unpublished", ie reverted to a draft, or pending review. Check the page:

  1. actually exists,
  2. has the title you're looking for
  3. the slug hasn't changed

(*note: although it could be a *Welcome Page* I'm thinking of here.)

### Double check the database

The easiest way to do this is to go into your database and see how many WP databases there are. Check each database and look for the underlying table structure, it sounds like you should be able to identify it pretty easily. If it's *not* a multisite install, the table prefixes *should* be `wp_` unless you changed them somewhere.

While you're playing around in the database, Take note of the database name and table prefix.

### Double check the folder structure

Have a look for a second instance of your folder structure, maybe you dropped it into the wrong place).

## 2. Check the WordPress installation is actually connected to the database

Check the WordPress configuration file `wp-config.php` is connected to the database. Check [`wp-config.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) sample from codex, you'll want to see the correct database name and table prefix in there.

From here you should also check the username has been setup correctly and is as you expect it. Remember, the database name will likely have a different prefix between hosting providers, unless you've managed to keep the same login name with each provider. ie, I'm talking about the database prefix here, not the table prefix.

(another note: most database connection issues will result in errors appearing on the page in lieu of your site, which leads me to believe it's at least partially setup correctly.)

**TEST**: What you can do is rename the old `wp-config.php` to something else and don't create a new one, then visit the website and it will lead you into setting it up again where you can enter the database details (your site info will still be intact, this will only reset your config file, not the database, although it could reset the connection between the filesystem and database).

## 3. Domain name propagation and DNS settings with your new host

As I mentioned previously, are you checking the right server? Are you sure the domain name has been propagated (if you're using the same domain name that is).

- Check the IP address with your DNS provider (for your domain name) is correctly pointed to your new server
- Then check that from your command line by typing `ping {your-domain-name}` and see that your IP address comes up
- Check the DNS settings with your web host are setup correctly and that your domain name points to where you want it to point to (ie, `public_html` or the relevant subdirectory there-of). (This resally does come back to point one, which if you covered it, this *shouldn't* be an issue
- Check that you dropped the files (and all the files) into the correct physical directory, ie `public_html` (or sub-dir)

If none of these help, please leave a comment with any further developments you've made and as much info as possible, and we can start looking in other areas.

*notes about the database name:

- when playing with WordPress directly, ie in the configuration files or the backend administration settings, the database will include your {username}[underscore or hyphen]{database-name}
- when playing in phpMyAdmin, they will already be included and you will just provide the {database-name}.

Answer (score 0):

Fellow this steps

1. export your sql from cpanel---phpmyadmin
2. make zip of your files in cpanel
3. import the file in new domain and extract it
4. create a database link to the new domain
5. go to new database which you have reacted through phpmyadmin--delete all the tables which was installed by wordpress.
6. import that sql file which you have downloaded from old website
7. and in phpmyadmin change the url to new domain name

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. export database from phpmyadmin.
2. zip your WordPress project via c-panel.
3. upload zip file on new domain via c-panel.
4. extract  zip file.
5. create new database and import old database in new phpmyadmin.
6. configure user name and password and database name.
7. change url in database table. from wp_operation table home_url and site_url

Thanks